# Integration PayPal to JSF Page (primefaces button)

Tags: primefaces, paypal, integration

are there a simple example for integrate a button for paypal and buy the item and redirect to my homepage?
I found the Rest API from PayPal but is there a easy example?

Should I have only one CDI-Bean? And all the other classes are in the paypal.jar ?
Could anybody help me, please

Comment: Did you found a solution?